# I am getting dns_probe_finished_nxdomain when opening my website which is hosted on google cloud because my ISP is refusing google dns server

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, dns, hosting, google-cloud-dns

I have recently migrated [my website](https://thenewcapitalcity.com/) from hostinger to google cloud. Everything was going very will untill I noticed that when I am on wifi the website don't open and gives me dns_probe_finished_nxdomain but while I am using mobile data every thing works perfectly.

I have invistegated in this issue and solved it but only on my network. I have added google dns server to my router settings [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unZmF.png) and this solved the problem on my network but I need a general solution that works for all networks bucause I will not be able to apply this solution on user's networks.
Also I have asked some of my friend to check if the website opens on their network. It worked on some networks and didn't work on the others.
Thanks in advance.